# How to console log an option of a JS object?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to console the value output of an option. In the example provided it would be the value of propOne, displayed here as 'value'. Thanks

```
var loadParallax = function(){
    $('.class-selector').parallax({
    propOne: 'value'
});
```

Comment: If you want to see  the values of the options for the `parallax` function, why not use the browser debugger and set a breakpoint inside the `parallax` function instead?

Comment: What is `.parallax()`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a reference to the passed in options object, then you can log it:

```
var options = {
    propOne: 'value'
};
var loadParallax = function(){
    $('.class-selector').parallax(options);
};

console.log(options.propOne); // => 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

For start, you should look into documentation for the plugin and search for something like getter, or options. Since you didn't state what plugin you use, I'll just give some tips, that could be useful.

Many plugins do this by method `.option('name_of_option')` or `.get('name_of_option')` or `.method('get', 'name_of_option')` so you can try for example `loadParallax.get('name_of_option')`. You can also try directly access the option as a property of object so you type `loadParallax.name_of_option` but many plugins disallows this.